# How to set the size of a Finder window?

Tags: macos, operating-systems, finder

Whenever I open the finder for specific directory, each directory remembers previous opened size, but I want to set default size for each finder screen that is going to be opened by me.

For example, the current situation is:

- xyz directory opens with size with previously opened size.
- abc directory opens with size with previously opened size.

I want to set a fixed size so that each directory opens in a fixed settings of a finder, but I don't know how.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set up a Finder window laid out how you want your defaults to be then go to the View menu and choose Show View Options. There is a button at the bottom "Use as Defaults" that you can press to make Finder windows open at that size with those view options by default.

Existing windows that have had their presets changed will need to be "reset" by deleting the `.DS_Store` file in that directory as the Finder window view options are stored in that file in each changed folder.

Comment: @Chealion - It's a problem that, you have to delete DS_Store file every time.